# automatically launch/open a file when it changes

Tags: macos, command-line, script, zsh

OS: OS X Lion

Shell: zsh

I'd like to automatically launch/open a file when it changes.

Background: i'm working on a windows vm, generating pdfs. Syncing via dropbox and when a file changes on dropbox (this is gets done in the windows vm) I'd like to open that pdf automatically.

Any hints/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) for that purpose. Launchd can be configured to automatically launch a program when a file path is modified.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac